# Characterizing injective homomorphisms on injective objects in the category of boolean algebras

Tags: category-theory, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to understand what type of injective homomorphism can have as domain an injective object in the category of boolean algebras. I have in mind two simple types of homomorphisms with domain a boolen algebra: the splitting ones and the complete ones. Do the two notions overlap when the domain is a complete boolean algebra?

Recall that $i$ splitting means that there is $j:C\to B$ homomorphism of boolean algebras such that $j\circ i=Id_B$.

Assume $i:B\to C$ is a splitting injective homomorphism of boolean algebras with $B$ complete. Is $i$ necessarily a complete homomorphism?

The converse holds. Assume $i:B\to C$ is a complete injective homomorphism of boolean algebras with $B$ complete. Then $i$ is splitting just because complete boolean algebras are the injective objects in the category of boolean algebras (we just need that $i$ is injective with domain a cba to have its splitting decomposition, not that $i$ is complete).

So the question really amounts to ask if injective homomorphism of booelan algebras wih domain a complete boolean algebra are complete homomorphisms.

Comment: What do you mean by "complete homomorphism"?

Comment: a homomorphism which preserves arbitrary suprema and not just finite ones.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer but since the question didn't get so much attention, I think this comment might be useful to work further on it.

The aim is to prove or disprove that if $\alpha: B \to C$ is a monomorphism between Boolean algebras and $B$ is complete, then $\alpha$ preserves arbitrary joins. Since joins are colimits when we think of $B$ as a category, and since left adjoints preserve colimits, it would be enough to prove that $\alpha$ has a right adjoint.

Defining $\beta: C \to B$ to be
$$\beta(c):=\bigvee\{b \in B: \alpha(b) \le c\}$$
doesn't always work.
$\beta$ is well-defined (since $B$ is complete), order-preserving and
\begin{equation}
(1) \quad\alpha(b) \le c \quad  \implies \quad b \le \beta(c)\text{.}
\end{equation}

The other direction is trickier. For example, as @curious on mathematics suggests, if $\alpha$ is the quotient map $\nu : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})/ I$, where is the ideal of finite sets, then $\beta$ does not satisfy the opposite direction in (1).

Comment: apologies but the answer is not correct. I have overlooked it on first sight. $\beta$ is well defined but does not satisfy in general the adjoint condition: consider the quotient map $\alpha:P(\mathbb{N})\to P(\mathbb{N})/Fin$; then $\alpha(\{n\})=0$ for all $n$ and $\alpha(\mathbb{N})=[\mathbb{N}]_{Fin}\neq\bigvee_{n\in\mathbb{N}}[\{n\}]=[\emptyset]_{Fin}$. So $\alpha$ does not preserves suprema. In fact $\beta([\emptyset]_{Fin})=\mathbb{N}$ according to your definition, so for $X$ infinite coinfinite $\alpha(X)\not\leq[\emptyset]_{Fin}$ even if $X\leq\beta([\emptyset]_{Fin})$.

Comment: My apologies to you. I'll edite my answer accordingly making it clear that my argument doesn't work.